# Scrapy with cronjob in Ubuntu

Tags: cron, scrapy

I'm trying to run my spider named `seo_filter_pages` from the crontab, but apparently nothing works. I work in Ubuntu. I created a virtual environment.
The path to scrapy is `/home/scrapy/venvScrapy/bin/scrapy` and python and python3 are also there. Path to spider: `/home/scrapy/tufelka/tufelka/spiders/`

Tried with and without PATH, but nothing starts. Here is an example of what I tried to write to the crontab.
What am I doing wrong? How can I check if it works or not?

1. `05 00 * * * PATH=/home/scrapy/venvScrapy/bin && cd /home/scrapy/tufelka && scrapy crawl seo_filter_pages >> /home/scrapy/spider.log 2>&1`
2. `05 00 * * * * cd /home/scrapy/tufelka && /home/scrapy/venvScrapy/bin/scrapy crawl seo_filter_pages >> /home/scrapy/spider.log 2>&1`

At the end I add a log file to record the actions, but it doesn't show up, which means the cron didn't work. The time is given as an example. In debugging I correct the time to check.

I don't want to use bush files.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to invoke the python binary before you run the scrapy binary.

For example, you can try:

`05 00 * * * * (cd /home/scrapy/tufelka && /home/scrapy/venvScrapy/bin/python /home/scrapy/venv/Scrapy/bin/scrapy crawl seo_filter_pages) >> /home/scrapy/spider.log 2>&1`

I actually don't think the parenthesis make a difference, that's just my personal preference.